# Need to get a multiline string to display in a textbox Java

Tags: java, multiline

I have a requirement in my project.
I generate a comment string in javascript.

```
Coping Option: Delete all codes and replace
Source Proj Num: R21AR058864-02
Source PI Last Name: SZALAI
Appl ID: 7924675; File Year: 7924675
```

I send this to server where I store it as a string in db and then after that I retrieve it back and show it in a textarea.

I generate it in javascript as :

```
        codingHistoryComment += 'Source Proj Num: <%=mDefault.getFullProjectNumber()%>'+'\n';
  codingHistoryComment += 'Source PI Last Name: <%=mDefault.getPILastName()%>'+'\n';
  codingHistoryComment += 'Appl ID: <%=mDefault.getApplId()%>; File Year: <%=mDefault.getApplId()%>'+'\n';
```

In java I am trying to replace the \n to 
 :

```
    String str = soChild2.getChild("codingHistoryComment").getValue().trim();
 if(str.contains("\\n")){
  str = str.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "<br>");
 }
```

However the textarea still get populated with the "\n" characters:

```
Coping Option: Delete all codes and replace\nSource Proj Num: R21AR058864-02\nSource PI Last Name: SZALAI\nAppl ID: 7924675; File Year: 7924675\n
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Vindhya "The textarea ..".  What is that exactly?  A java.awt.TextArea?  A javax.swing.JTextArea?  Something entirely different?  Note that these questions would be unnecessary if you had posted an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html) rather than code snippets.  But as a general point, programming is a precise business.  Please bring that precision to your on-line discussions and debugging.

Comment: Are you writing the code in Java or Javascript? Tag and title say Java but you mention Javascript a couple of times in your question.

Comment: I am writing code in java but my client involves javascript in jsp. Hence I gave the code snippet for better idea.

Comment: No. I am not using JTextArea. Its the html textarea. I have to display a page with a textarea containing the string as multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

> In java I am trying to replace the \n to

Don't replace the "\n". A JTextArea will parse that as a new line string.

Trying to convert it to a "br" tag won't help either since a JTextArea does not support html.

I always just use code like the following to populate a text area with text:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
textArea.setText("1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n0");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// automatically wrap lines
jTextArea.setLineWrap( true );
// break lines on word, rather than character boundaries.
jTextArea.setWrapStyleWord( true );
```

From [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/jtextarea.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a test that works, try it out:

```
String str = "This is a test\r\n test.";
if(str.contains("\r\n")) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Javascript (since you try to replace with a HTML break line):

A HTML textarea newline should be a newline character `\n` and not the HTML break line `<br>`. Try to use the code below to remove extra slashes instead of your current if statement and replace. Don't forget to assign the value to the textarea after the replacement.

Try:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\n", "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
if(str.contains("\\n")){
```

Instead of `"\\n"` you just need `"\n"`

Then instead of `"\n"` you need `"\\n"` here:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "<br>");
```

By the way, the `if(str.contains()` is not really needed because it won't hurt to run replace all if there is no `"\n"` characters.

Comment: I think we need to have \\n since \n will escape the slash right? Still It doesnt work. The \n is still there in the String. :(

Comment: @Vidhya, I just tested it, and this method works fine.  Can you provide a SSCCE that does not.

Comment: Here is a test that works, try it out:  String str = "This is a test\n test.";
     if(str.contains("\n")){
      System.out.println(str);
      str = str.replaceAll("(\\r\\n|\\n)", "<br>");
      System.out.println(str);
     }