# Multi-line string support issue in textbox?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I am facing a problem in textbox to display multiple lines in it.

For example, I just copied a three lines of text in winword and paste it in the textbox. Only the first line from winword will be displayed in the textbox. The other two lines will not be in textbox, and I don't know why.

I need this support in the chat application in Java, so I have to implement it.

Please help me to solve the issue or give some ideas or sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't show multiple lines in `textbox`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846424/need-to-get-a-multiline-string-to-display-in-a-textbox-java see if this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mistaking the

```
<input type="text" />
```

with the `textarea` tag. For multiple lines, you can use a textarea as follows:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
    Some text here
</textarea>
```

See more details on the `textarea` tag [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Textbox by definition supports a single line only. You are looking for a textarea.

Comment: But I need this support to textbox only.

Comment: Sorry, it is simply not possible to display multiple lines in a textbox. If you could expand upon your use case, maybe I could help you find a different solution.

Comment: Um... You need to explain your use case first.

Comment: I just explain it as simple. I am having one textbox to type the message and button to send the message.Also one textarea to display the message...Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with a `textbox`. In HTML, you have multiple input types:

```
<input type="text" name="single-line" />
<textarea name="multiline" />
```

The input with type `text` supports only one line of input, while the textarea supports multiple lines. The textarea is by default a couple of rows in most browsers, you can use CSS to style it to show only one line at a time.

```
textarea { height: 1em; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in text box html code

textbox id="textbox" textmode="multiline"

or you can use

Enter your comments here...

Thanks.

Comment: You can use 

<textarea class="ClassName" name="name" id="id" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>

Comment: But I need this support to textbox only.I used textarea to display chat messages.